# Можно ли объявлять классы в SVG-файле через <style>?

Tags: css, svg

Можно ли объявлять классы в SVG-файле, испольуя `<style>`?

Если да, то подключать их к тегам через `class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стили в svg-файле описываются вот так:

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    .circle {
      fill: orange;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 10px;
    }
    /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <circle class="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
```

Можно описывать как классами, так и отдельными элементами.
Подробнее - [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style).